# How to properly change target framework to .NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I built an application with target framework .NET 4.6 using MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6 using Visual Studio 2017 on my Windows 7 machine. I'm now being told that I should have built the application to target .NET 4.0 because the production environment only has 4.0 installed. So I changed the target framework to 4.0 but now the application will not build on my machine.

I'm guessing I also need to downgrade MVC and EF. How is the proper way of doing this?

And which versions of MVC and EF should I install?

Do I need to make any manual changes to web.config?

Comment: Irrespective of the answers, I am really surprised that some one being asked to develop an ASP.NET MVC application on .NET version 4.0 in end of 2018 while the latest version of .NET is 4.7.2 and .NET Core is 2.2!

Comment: .NET 4.5.1 support ended on January 12, 2016.  It's highly unlikely that the production environment has only 4.0, and if so is a bigger problem. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17455/lifecycle-faq-net-framework

Answer (score 3):

There is no *"proper"* way, you have 3 options, in my favorite order:

- Update the server and install the latest .net version. (at the time .net 4.6). Make sure used libraries are up to date and not end of life.
- Start over in a new project and make sure you target version 4.0: you can copy most of your source files. You'll probably get some compiler errors, but usually they are easily fixed. This way you'll have the benefit that the used template matches the framework and packages version(s).
- Re-target the used framework in the project properties and replace the packages which are installed and hope for the best (sometimes you need other packages). Hopefully you used the package manager to install those packages. Maybe the `update-packages` command helps, but be sure to backup your project first. Some packages become obsolete after time, some are renamed. This is what will cause issues. Also, some of the Methods/API calls will be different, so some rework will be needed.

As for the rest of your questions:

> I'm guessing I also need to downgrade MVC and EF. How is the proper way of doing this?

`Use the nuget package manager`

> And which versions of MVC and EF should I install?

`The nuget package manager will fix this for you.`

> Do I need to make any manual changes to web.config?

`Sometimes: yes.`

Comment: Do I need to install .net framework 4.0 on my machine? Because if I have 4.5 installed then will the DLLs still reference 4.5 even though I target 4.0 in the visual studio.

Comment: If you are using visual studio, usually all .net versions are already present on your machine and you don't need to worry about that. You can check this the installer of visual studio 2017, at the section called `individual components`

Comment: I also found out that if I use .NET 4.0 then I can only use MVC 4 which apparently cannot be developed on VS2017 so I'll have to downgrade VS as well?

Comment: Hmmm... it seems you are correct, I missed that. Indeed it seems that the MVC 4 template is missing. I have searched for them [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=asp.net%204&target=VS&category=Tools&vsVersion=&subCategory=All&sortBy=Relevance) but couldn't find them. You can start an MVC 4 project, but it's an empty template and then you need to "rebuild" the template all by yourself. Installing VS2015 will help you.... but still; I wouldn't recommend it. In the past, installing an older VS version over a newer could lead to complications.